# Represent operation in UML class diagram C#

Tags: c#, .net, uml

I am looking for some help to represent operation in UML class diagram.
Inside of class, it is separated into two pieces, attributes and operations. In operations part, I want to create method,

```
public void NewSale(Dictionary<int, Transaction> d){
  //
}
```

I wrote in UML diagram,

```
+ NewSale(Dictionary<int, Transaction>)
```

and it turns out,

```
public void NewSale(object Dictionary<int, object Transaction>)
{
}
```

How can I fix this? (* I have Transaction class).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what tool you are using (Visual Studio?) however I believe the problem is that you don't have any parameter names, just types, in your operation definition. For example...

```
+ NewSale (dictionary: Dictionary<int, Transaction>)
```

...might work. However I'm not sure how your code generator will be handling generic types. It looks like it has interpreted your generic's "," as a *parameter separator*, translating your generic type into two parameters, one of type `Dictionary<int` and the next of `Transaction>`.

Comment: Can you tell me how this textual UML notation is called?

Comment: I am using VS 2015. I will try this and let you know

Comment: I don’t think it’s code per se. I only wrote this in a code block because using a + in SO generates a bullet!